# Keeping Service Bus Connection alive for duration of app lifecycle

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus

Hi I am using the new nodejs sdk to connect to servicebus. What is the proper way to keep receiving messages as long as my application is running? The example code shows 2 ways of listening for messages:

*Method 1 - Receive Batch*

```
  const receiver = client.getReceiver();

  try {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      const messages = await receiver.receiveBatch(1, 5);
      if (!messages.length) {
        console.log("No more messages to receive");
        break;
      }
      console.log(`Received message #${i}: ${messages[0].body}`);
      await messages[0].complete();
    }
    await client.close();
  } finally {
    await ns.close();
  }
}
```

*Method 2 - Streaming Listener*

```
  try {
    receiver.receive(onMessageHandler, onErrorHandler, { autoComplete: false });

    // Waiting long enough before closing the receiver to receive messages
    await delay(5000);

    await receiver.close();
    await client.close();
  } finally {
    await ns.close();
  }
```

I went with method 2, on startup, and basically never close the client. But after a period of time the connection just stops working and the messages don't get received anymore (stuck in the queue).

**What is the correct way to receive messages "forever"?:**

- Re-establish a new client (open and close eg every minute) with method 1, OR
- Re-establish a new client (open and close eg every minute) with method 2, OR
- Some kind of polling system (how)?

Comment: Two ways are in essence you're building your own message pump vs built in message pump. Connectivity issues can and will occur. You'll have to handle that, but not every minute, when an appropriate exception is taking place.

Comment: @SeanFeldman I suspected as much, hence my asking. Maybe there's a way of detecting exceptions specific to the connection (as opposed to the message) and then closing the client and reopening a new one? Out of my depth here.

Comment: Clients have `.IsClosedOrClosing` property you could check prior to using (or if you're using a factory/pool). For exceptions, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions) might be helpful, though it's a bit dated (references old client only).

Comment: @SeanFeldman Thank you. I was honestly thinking of just recycling the connection every 30 minutes (close the client altogether and reopen). But I will  try this `isClosedOrClosing` check first, and fall back to recycling if i get no joy. Thanks for all the tips!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a late reply, but... Version 7 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK offers a solution in order to tackle this specific problem of disconnects and reconnection.

The `subscribe` method(which is equivalent to the `receive` method in your code snippet) can be leveraged which would run **forever** and is capable of recovering from fatal errors as well.

You can refer to the [receiveMessagesStreaming.ts](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/typescript/src/receiveMessagesStreaming.ts) sample code that uses version 7 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` has been released recently.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)

Comment: Does this subscribe method have an equivalent in the Python libraries? I have looked and cannot find one, not sure if I am looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I believe this is the equivalent in Python, https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus#receive-messages-from-a-queue